# loop unrolling with dynamic parallelism decrease the time performance

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I have a simple program to calculate square root, loop unrolling was done as

loop unrolling

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
__global__ void square(float *a, int N,int idx);


// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void first(float *arr, int N)
{
  int idx = 2*(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
  int n=N;
  //printf("%d\n",n);
  for(int q=0;q<2;q++)
  {
  if(N<2000)
  {
  arr[idx+q] = arr[idx+q] * arr[idx+q];
  }
  }

}



// main routine that executes on the host
int main(void)
{
  clock_t start = clock(),diff;
  float *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
  const int N = 1000;  // Number of elements in arrays
  size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
  a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
  // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
  cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // Do calculation on device:
  int block_size = 4;
  //int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
  first <<< 4, 128 >>> (a_d, N);
  //cudaThreadSynchronize();
  // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
  cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // Print results
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);
  // Cleanup
  free(a_h); cudaFree(a_d);
  diff = clock() - start;
 int msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

 printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);

}
```

then realizing that the loop calculation can be minimized with dynamic parallelism .

unrolling with dynamic parallelism was implemented as

**unrolling with dynamic parallelism**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
__global__ void square(float *a, int N,int idx);


// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void first(float *arr, int N)
{
  int idx = 2*(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
  int n=N;
  square <<< 1,2 >>> (arr, n,idx);


}

__global__ void square(float *a, int N,int idx)
{
  int tdx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  printf("%d\n",N);
  if(N<2000)
  {
  a[tdx+idx] = a[tdx+idx] * a[tdx+idx];
  }
}

// main routine that executes on the host
int main(void)
{
  clock_t start = clock(),diff;
  float *a_h, *a_d;  // Pointer to host & device arrays
  const int N = 1000;  // Number of elements in arrays
  size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
  a_h = (float *)malloc(size);        // Allocate array on host
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);   // Allocate array on device
  // Initialize host array and copy it to CUDA device
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
  cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // Do calculation on device:
  int block_size = 4;
  //int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
  first <<< 4, 128 >>> (a_d, N);
  //cudaThreadSynchronize();
  // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
  cudaMemcpy(a_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // Print results
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d %f\n", i, a_h[i]);
  // Cleanup
  free(a_h); cudaFree(a_d);
  diff = clock() - start;
 int msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

 printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);

}
```

the implementation of dynamic parallelism with unrolling takes more time for executio than only unrolling. Aren,t we suppose to improve execution time with dynamic parallelism in such case?

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic parallelism is mainly useful in cases where you have parallelism that is dynamic. That is: cases where you don't know how much parallelism you're going to need until you've done some calculation. Rather than transfer data back to the host which is then instantly fed into parameterising another launch, you launch from within the kernel. In this pattern, with memcpys between kernel launches avoided, you'll see speedup.

In your example above this is not the case. You could have just launched twice as many threads from the host. There's nothing dynamic required as there's no parallelism available there that you didn't know about at the time of the first kernel launch.

Furthermore, performance requirements for kernels launched using dynamic parallelism are similar to that of those launched from the host. You have to launch a reasonable amount of work or the launch latency will dominate your computation time.

Comment: You may wish to add that the child kernel launch overhead completely masks the computation time to execute only two child threads in this case. For the reasons you have expounded in your answer, launching a new kernel is only disrupting from the computational point of view.